# Ignore ftplib's 550 error when file does not exist and and continue with other files

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I have problem with ignoring an error and just going on with other commands. The code below is checking if file exists (using `FTP.size`) and prints message if so. And - here is problem. When it doesn't find file in this main directory, it should go to `/folder2` and look for file here. Instead it throws traceback error (which I "silenced") and doesn't go to second folder...

```
from ftplib import FTP
import sys
sys.tracebacklimit = 0


ftp = FTP(host="ip")
loginRepsonse = ftp.login(user='name', passwd='password')
print(loginRepsonse)

fileName = "2022121414040114FTPtestLarge.txt"
# fileName = str(input('What is name of your file? '))

size = ftp.size(fileName)


if isinstance(size, int):
    print("File exists!")
else :    
    ftp.cwd('/folder2')
    if isinstance(size, int):
        print("File exists in another directory!")
```

When file exists it's all cool, it shows that file indeed exist, but when not... This error below appears and execution ends, without looking to second folder...

> ftplib.error_perm: 550 Could not get file size.

My FTP has only "main" directory and one subfolder - code needs to check two folders (main, then 2nd folder if file wasn't found). How to ignore this error and continue searching?

Below is whole error output with non-existing file (same happens for EXISTING file, but in different directory, which I can't access):

```
230 Login successful.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\CODES+SCRIPTS\ftp.py", line 13, in <module>
    size = ftp.size(fileName)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ftplib.py", line 630, in size
    resp = self.sendcmd('SIZE ' + filename)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ftplib.py", line 281, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ftplib.py", line 254, in getresp
    raise error_perm(resp)
ftplib.error_perm: 550 Could not get file size.
```

Below is another code I tried:

```
size = ftp.size(fileName)

from ftplib import FTP, error_perm
try:
    size = ftp.size(fileName)
    print(f"File exists {size}")
    ftp.cwd('/test')          #checks subfolder(or it should..)
    if isinstance(size, int):
         print("File exists in another directory!")
except error_perm as e:
    print(f"File does not exist anywhere: {e}")
```

---

This is working (not finished) code based on the answer below.

```
from ftplib import FTP, error_perm

ftp = FTP(host=host)
loginRepsonse = ftp.login(user=user, passwd=passwd)
print(loginRepsonse)

def repeat():
    fileName = str(input('>>> What is name of your file? \n'))
    try:
        size = ftp.size(fileName)
        print(f"File exists in main directory.")
    except error_perm as e:
        pass
        print(f"File does not exist in main directory.")

    try:
        ftp.cwd('/testLAB')
        size = ftp.size(fileName)
        if isinstance(size, int):
                print("File exists in subfolder!")
    except:
        print(f"File does not exist anywhere yet.")

while True:
   repeat()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just catch the appropriate exception:

```
from ftplib import FTP, error_perm
 
# ...

try:
    size = ftp.size(fileName)
    print(f"File exists {size}")
except error_perm as e:
    print(f"File does not exist (or other error): {e}");
```